# Python type variables wrong message

Tags: python, python-2.7

Why do I keep getting the message wrong when I run this code in the python console? For a I enter 5.

```
a = raw_input("type a number here: ")

if type(a) != int == False:

    print ("Input verified!")

elif type(a) != float == False:

    print ("Input verified!")

else:

    print ("Wrong!")
```

Comment: Are you trying to check `if isinstance(a, (int, float))`? Because **it is always `str`**.

Answer (score 4):

`type(a) != int == False` is a *chained comparison*, and evaluates as:

```
(type(a) != int) and (int == False)
```

`int == False` is always going to be false.

Don't use `== False` or `== True` in boolean tests; just test directly or use `not`. Also, use `isinstance()` to test for specific types:

```
if isinstance(a, int):
    # ...
```

However, `raw_input()` returns an object of type `str`, *always*. It won't produce an object of type `int` or `float`. You need to convert explicitly using `float()`, and then use exception handling to handle inputs that are not valid integer or floating point numbers:

```
try:
    result = float(a)
    print 'Input verified'
except ValueError:
    print 'Sorry, I need a number'
```

Also see [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)